# Is it possible to purchase Iranian Rial in China?

Tags: money, china, exchange, iran

A friend of mine in China is looking for a place to buy Iraian Rial (`IRR`).

I know that in the west Iran is financially blockaded so presume that this is one of the currencies that is not dealt with by money changing establishments.

But I wouldn't be surprised if China doesn't take part in the financial blockade. So do we know if it's possible to change `CNY` to `IRR` in China?

Comment: I have a bunch left over, if there's some way to get it to you...

Comment: I'm not in China any more (-:

Comment: Well, to your friend... ;)

Comment: I know that Persian restaurants offer money exchange.

Answer (score 5):

Bank Melli Iran has a branch in Hong Kong (surprisingly none in the mainland):

> 18/F Kam Sang Building
>
> 257, Des Voeux Road Central,
>
> Hong Kong
>
> Tel : +852 37614444
>
> Fax : +852 28684692
>
> Swift : MELIHKHH
>
> Email : info@hk.mellibank.com

Tejarat Bank also has a representation office in Beijing:

> Office C208, Beijing Lufthansa Center.
>
> No. 50, Liangmaqiao Road, Chaoyang District, Beijing (100125)
>
> Tel : (86-10) 84551116
>
> Fax : (86-10) 84551117
>
> E-mail : bt_beijingrep@tejarat-bank.com

Both should exchange IRR.

Comment: It would have been great if you could also give us some links in case they might change either their address or numbers in future.